# Problem with the div on the opacity background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginner web developer.

I have this code:

```css
.modal {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
}

.modal__overlay {
  background: #000000;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 600;
}

.modal__wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.5em;
}

#modal__title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#modal__desc {
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.closePopupBtn {
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ED1B23;
  line-height: 1.65;
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.modal input:focus~label {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
  transform: scale(0.97);
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
}

.modal__overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  z-index: -100;
}

input:checked~.modal__overlay {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 800;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal">
  <input id="modal__trigger" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="modal__trigger">pokaz</label>
  <div class="modal__overlay" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal__title" aria-describedby="modal_desc">
    <div class="modal__wrap">
      <img src="{{ asset('img/popup1.png') }}" class="img-fluid">
      <h2 id="modal__title">This is your modal content</h2>
      <p id="modal__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus.
        In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
      <label for="modal__trigger" class="closePopupBtn">Zamknij</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code works fine, but the popup in the center of the screen is also transparent. I would like only the background to be transparent - the popup should not be transparent.

How to fix it?

Preview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/popup.html
After click "show" I have animation. It's work fine. My problem is only with div with text

Comment: just increase opactity to 1 and change the background color as you want

Comment: `input:checked ~ .modal__overlay {

background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
      
}`

try this this worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="modal">
        <input id="modal__trigger" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="modal__trigger">pokaz</label>
        <div class="modal__overlay" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal__title" aria-describedby="modal_desc">
            <div class="modal__wrap">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/popup1.png') }}" class="img-fluid">
                <h2 id="modal__title">This is your modal content</h2>
                <p id="modal__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac laoreet elit. Phasellus dignissim purus vitae urna cursus, quis congue ligula tristique. Ut nec blandit risus. Donec at orci ut justo venenatis viverra. Suspendisse in volutpat lacus. In enim est, dapibus eget ipsum sed, suscipit ultrices diam.</p>
                <label for="modal__trigger" class="closePopupBtn">Zamknij</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <style>
    .modal {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}

.modal__overlay {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: none;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 600;
}

.modal__wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;

    margin-top: 30px;
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1.5em;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#modal__title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#modal__desc {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.closePopupBtn {
    clear: both;
    color: white;
    background-color: #ED1B23;
    line-height: 1.65;
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


.modal input:focus ~ label {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.97);
    transform: scale(0.97);
}

input {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
}


.modal__overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    z-index: -100;
    background-color: black;
}

.modal__overlay::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

input:checked ~ .modal__overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    z-index: 800;
}

input:checked ~ .modal__overlay::after {
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.5;
}


</style>
```

Comment: Almost perfect :) When the popup closes it closes you can see a black background

Comment: it happens because the original color is black and that effect is also shown in your question code

Comment: I update my answer, in that new answer your problem was solved, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting tranbsparency

```
.modal__overlay {
opacity: 0; <---------- delete this line
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
z-index: -100;
```

}

Comment: It's not help. When I remove this - my popup is visible when page was loaded. I need show this popup after click "show". Please try my code in preview :)

Comment: Set the opacity: 0 on father div .modal, an make the father div visible when needed